# There are 2 form fields as reg no and full name in html. I want to fill full name when reg no associated with name is entered using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Registrationm form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <!--here at runtime i want to fill full name when user enters rno associated with fullname--> 

    Registration number:<input type="text" id="rno"/>

    Full name:<input type="text id="name"/>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want your system to do a look up in the database to get the full name if there's a record that has the entered registration number? Please expand on what you'd like to achieve and what your problems are (error messages, etc.) and have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not in the database. Lets say I want to create an object with multiple properties (fullname, reg no) and create an array of objects and get the value on frontend using javascript at runtime.

Comment: I've added an answer; if you can include this information about what you're trying to do in the question, it'll provide more clarity which can help users in the future who may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, here's what you need to do:

1. Define a list of objects which include a name and a registration number.
2. Populate these objects to an array.
3. Have your input's onchange/onkeyup event filter the array for elements having the supplied registration number.

The snippet below supplies pseudocode that does similar things as an instructive example for you to adapt to your needs.

Please address any issues you have applying it in another question if necessary.

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

const rectangles = [];

window.onload = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
  {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    let y = x / 2;
    let shape = new Rectangle(y, x);
    rectangles.push(shape);
  }
  console.log(rectangles);
}

const getRectanglesWithHeight = (height) => {
    const container = document.querySelector(".results");
  container.innerHTML = "";
  
    const results = rectangles.filter(x => x.height == height);
  for (let result of results)
  {
    let i = 1;
    let markup = `<p>${i}<br />
    Height: ${result.height}<br />
    Width: ${result.width}</p>
    <div style="border:1px solid #000; height: ${result.height}px; width: ${result.width}px;">`
    
    container.innerHTML += markup;
  }
}

const getRectanglesWithWidth = (width) => {
    const container = document.querySelector(".results");
  container.innerHTML = "";
  
    const results = rectangles.filter(x => x.width == width);
  for (let result of results)
  {
    let i = 1;
    let markup = `<p>${i}<br />
    Height: ${result.height}<br />
    Width: ${result.width}</p>
    <div style="border:1px solid #000; height: ${result.height}px; width: ${result.width}px;">`
    
    container.innerHTML += markup;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
Height:<br />
<input type="number" id="height" onkeyup="getRectanglesWithHeight(this.value)" />
</p>
<p>
Width:<br />
<input type="number" id="width" onkeyup="getRectanglesWithWidth(this.value)" />
</p>

<div class="results">

</div>
```